# dplyr::gather - getting error message but do not know why

Tags: r

I am getting this error:

> Error in gather(., key = "Capture", value = "Length", t1:t5, na.rm =
>   TRUE, : could not find function "gather"

I have called in `dplyr`, and had no previous problems with this function. All that happened was that r crashed and when I reopened it, this function wasn't working, any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `gather` function in `dplyr`. You need `tidyr::gather()`.

You probably had `tidyr` loaded before R crashed so didn't have any issues. However, you need to reload required libraries whenever you restart R.

Comment: Course! thank you, simple fix

Comment: @Cailin, cool, cool! Can you please then accept the answer.